# Can't use npx create-react-app "no longer support global installation of Create React App"

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I can't create a new application using the create-react-app.
The command I am using is `npx create-react-app appname --template typescript`.

The error I get is:

```
You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App
```

I removed the global package with `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`. I then checked the packaged is not installed globally by

1. Running `npm list -g`
2. Checking the folder C:\Users\my-user\AppData\roaming\npm

But create-react-app keeps saying I have globally installed "create-react-app 4.0.3".

After all I did clean cache with `npm cache clean --force` and reboot computer but with the same result.

I am runnig on windows 10, npm 7.18.1 and node 16.4.0

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of node do you have running?  Could you please run `nvm list`?  All the versions install should displayed and the one in use should be annotated.

Comment: Following the first answer to this question might help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61362017/removing-old-versions-of-create-react-app

Comment: I have added the node version (16.4.0) and I tried to follow the thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61362017/removing-old-versions-of-create-react-app but it did not work

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11816) is a related issue

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This caught me too.  You need to run

```
npx clear-npx-cache
```

Comment: Would of been nice if the CRA team added this bit for those unfamiliar with this command. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my instance, I had an older version of `create-react-app` installed globally with yarn, and simply removing it fixed the issue.

```
yarn global remove create-react-app
```

Or, for NPM

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

I was then able to run `npx create-react-app my-app` without issue.